# Populating new form data from REST api

Tags: rest

I've come from a background of ASP.Net MVC where when the user wants to create a new entity the server returns values to populate drop down lists(for example).

Now I'm doing a UI that is invoking a REST Api. I have my urls for creating/retrieving etc but this is purely for actual resources. How would the REST be defined to get data to populate the create form.

For example:

a user wants to create a new order. They go to the 'create order' screen and need to select their payment method. They have 3 payment methods (card, paypal, amazon) but the logic on the server side knows that amazon cannot be accepted on this order. How would I go about letting the UI know what can be populated in the drop down list using REST?

I can't seem to get this to fit into REST principles but then I don't want the user to submit amazon and then the server return a Bad Request, just seems bad implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Is payment selection based on a user? Why do you need to let the UI know? If It cannot be accepted in that particular use case, then don't return it.

Comment: So payment method is based on the user, which can be retrieved from `/user/id/paymentemthod`which can populate the drop down list. But in this case one method isn't supported so I don't think it should be displayed at all. But the UI won't have this logic unfortunately

Comment: Your quite right, it shouldn't be displayed. If you're building the API, you could just refactor the logic that returns the payment methods. I may be missing something here, apologize.

Comment: But the call to `/user/id/paymentmethod` isn't aware of what the user is trying to do (e.g. what order they are trying to place) so can't filter at this point